# Learning php Classes, stuck on __contruct();

Tags: php, oop

So I'm trying to learn phpOOP after stopping programming for a few years, so I'm a bit rusty.

Anyway, I have a class blogEntry so I can display blog entries that have been cleaned with the function cleanForDisplay by echo'ing $blogEntry->article for example. But I am receiving no errors, and the variable is not being displayed.

Thanks

```
class blogEntry
 {
  var $headline;
  var $author;
  var $date;
  var $image;
  var $imagecaption;
  var $article;

  public function __contruct()
  {
    $this->headline = cleanForDisplay($row['headline']);
    $this->author = cleanForDisplay($row['postedby']);
    $this->imagecaption = cleanForDisplay($row['imagecaption']);
    $this->article = cleanForDisplay($row['article']);
    $this->image = $row['image'];
    $this->date = $row['date'];
  }
}
```

Comment: In your constructor, where are you getting the values for $row['headline'], $row['postedby'] etc. ? also, how are you accessing this class ?

Comment: Where are you getting `$row` from? Typically, you should pass an ID to the constructor, and then look up the item in a database using prepared statements. `contruct` !== `construct`.

Comment: also, is cleanForDisplay a function of the blogEntry class ?

Comment: ^^ and if it's not, it should be part of another class really, for true OOP.

Comment: When you say 'the variable is not being displayed', where are you echoing it out to the screen? (in another function?). I would do a var_dump($instance->article); to see if the variable has been set.

Comment: @Austen, please, never put computation in the constructors of a class. It makes it impossible to test the instances. Also `var` statements have been considered archaic since 5.0 was released. Just the fact that you are using them means that your instances have broken encapsulation. It also would indicate, that the materials you are using, have been created before 2005.

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo, the magic method is `__construct()` and you are not receiving any error because the constructor is not mandatory in PHP.

Also, the `$row` variable is not defined, so you fields will be null even with the constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Your method is spelt incorrectly. It should read `__construct()`.

Secondly, you are not passing in any parameters to the method, and thus, `$row` is undefined.

Consider the following:

```
public function __construct($row)
{
 $this->headline = cleanForDisplay($row['headline']);
 $this->author = cleanForDisplay($row['postedby']);
 $this->imagecaption = cleanForDisplay($row['imagecaption']);
 $this->article = cleanForDisplay($row['article']);
 $this->image = $row['image'];
 $this->date = $row['date'];
}
```

`$row` is passed in as the parameter, and therefore, the variables you are trying to set will be defined.

The `blogEntry` class can be initialized as follows:

```
$blogEntry = new blogEntry($rowFromDB);
```